# Multiple XML/XSLT files in PHP, transform one with XSLT and add others but process it first with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am processing XML files transformations with XSLT in PHP correctly. Actually I use this code:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->LoadXML($xml_contents);

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load($xsl_file);

$proc = new XSLTProcesoor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

echo $proc->transformToXml($xml);
```

`$xml_contents` is the XML processed with PHP, this is done by including the XML file first and then assigning `$xml_contents = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();`. This forces to process the PHP code on the XML, and it works perfectly.

My problem is that I use more than one XML file and this XML files has PHP code on it that need to be processed AND have a XSLT file associated to process the data. Actually I'm including this files in XSLT with the next code:

```
<!-- First I add the XML file -->
<xsl:param name="menu" select="document('menu.xml')" />

<!-- Next I add the transformations for menu.xml file -->
<xsl:include href="menu.xsl" />

<!-- Finally, I process it on the actual ("parent") XML -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="$menu/menu" />
```

My questiion is how I can handle this. I need to add mutiple XML(+XSLT) files to my first XML file that will containt PHP so it needs to be processed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are missing one part of the process chain. If I understand this correctly the chain is: XML+PHP -> PHP pre-process -> XSLT, and you want the last step to be aware of the same data that **is aviable in the first step**. When you build the XML plus the embbeded PHP, you know wich stylesheet to apply. Then, do apply it.

Comment: @Alejandro: I don't get it. I know what XML and what XSLT I'll use but what I want is to add extra XML and extra XSLT where the XML included from the master XSLT can be pre-processed with PHP. So the chain will be: PHP Controller calls to render "example.xml" -> PHP loads XML and process it and associate a "example.xslt" automatically -> Print output. In the step where example.xslt is associated, this example.xslt contains various includes for XML and XSLT extras. I need to pre-process this extra XML files.

Comment: Then you need to refrase your question because now it's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 solutions, maybe one of them will be ok.

Not tested, but you can implement a custom stream in PHP.

```
<?php

// define your custom stream, should process xslt
class CustomStream extends streamWrapper {
    // http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php
}

// declare your custom stream
stream_wrapper_register('extra', 'CustomStream');

// then load your preprocessed on the fly in your example.xsl
$xml_contents = <<<EOF
...
<xsl:param name="menu" select="document('extra://menu.xml')" />
EOF;


?>
```

Solution n°2, register php functions in your xslt, and play with it :

```
<?php
// declare your function
// see http://www.php.net/manual/fr/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php
function resolve($xml_contents, $xsl_file=null) {
    $dom = new DomDocument;
    $dom->loadXML($xml_contents);
    if ($xsl == null) {
        return $dom;
    }

    $xsl = new DOMDocument;
    $xsl->load($xsl_file);

    $proc = new XSLTProcessor;

    $proc->registerPHPFunctions('resolve');
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

    return $proc->transformToDoc($xml_contents);
}


// then handle your master xsl
$xsl_contents = <<<EOF
...
<xsl:param name="menu" select="php:function('resolve', 'menu.xml', 'menu.xsl')" />
EOF;

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml_contents);

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->loadXML($xsl_contents);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor;

$proc->registerPHPFunctions('resolve');
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

return $proc->transformToDoc($xml_contents);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "XML file that will contain PHP", but I'm guessing that you need php to interfere with the XSLT processing after it's started. Otherwise you'd be using PHP to manipulate the source XML *before* any XSLT transformation is run.

There's php functionality that allows you to run arbitrary php inside XSLT stylesheet during processing, although it is an extension of the standard XSLT.

There's [more info and examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php).

**EDIT:**

On the second thought, if you simply need to specify what XML to load without hardcoding it into XSLT, document() function may use source XML nodes for names of the files to load. So you just generate names in XML, and then have document() read them for further reference in the template.